# Google sheet copy data from table to other tab while respecting the format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I was hoping if I could get a bit of help on a script I wrote in google app scripts. I have a google sheet with two tabs "TESTPLANNING" and "Sheet3". My goal is to copy the table I have in the "TESTPLANNING" to "Sheet3" at the click of a button all while respecting the formatting of the table in my first sheet.

I have attached an image of my two sheets, the top image represents the table in "TESTPLANNING" tab and bottom image is in "Sheet3". https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO4pd.jpg

So far I have a working script which clears my table of all values, I activate this by clicking the "reset" button. I want the "submit" button submit my table to "Sheet3" in the same table format.

So far my code copies the values from range A3:H7 (shown in lower screenshot), however I want an exact copy of the table in "sheet3" (not just the values). How can I achieve this ? I'm relatively new to this so any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Working code for submit button:

```html
function submit() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cal_sh = ss.getSheetByName('TESTPLANNING');
  const raw_sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  const ranges = ['A3:H7'];
  const values = [];
  ranges.forEach(r=>values.push(...cal_sh.getRange(r).getValues().flat()));
  raw_sh.getRange(raw_sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,values.length).setValues([values]);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyFromOneSheetToAnother() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('TESTPLANNING');
  const rg = sh.getRange('A3:H7');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  const org = osh.getRange('A3');//only need upper left corner
  rg.copyTo(org);
}
```

[Range.coptyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

Comment: Thanks ! this works for the table. Would you know how I can get the next table to appear below the one in "sheet3". I would like "sheet3" to be some sort of log of all my submissions. I think I might need to use an "appendRow" function however not sure how I can implement it in my script.

Comment: Put it at `'A'+3+7-3+1`

Comment: script is now has `osh.appendRow(['A'+3+7-3+1]);` output is only showing "#NUM!" in "Sheet3" underneath table unfortunately.

Comment: No I was just telling you how to calculate the where  the output range would be so the next output would be at `org=osh.getRange('A8');` I have no idea where you got the idea to append that as a row.  I have nothing like that in my code.

Comment: Yes that works for A8. However I need it to work continually. How can I set this up for it to be recursive? I've tried inserting variables into `org=osh.getRange('A'+?);` so that an increment of 8 is automatically added every time, so in my case it would be '+8' for the first submission '+16' next '+24' .... but no success in getting something working.

Comment: Well you have to put your thinking cap on for that.  Where do you suppose that I got the 7 - 3 +1 from?